# Need to Implement dependent lookups like dependent picklists

Tags: force.com, lookup, dynamic-binding, dependent-lookup

I have two lookups, one for country and one for state. I want that on change of country corresponding state values flows into state look up. How can I implement this? I cannot use picklist due to some restrictions. Please suggest.

Comment: What about the new country and state picklists in beta? I think that would address this.

Comment: did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try using dependant lookups and or lookup filters.

http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_lookup_filters_dependent_lookups.htm